# Serving a Python Page with Windows / Apache / Mod_WSGI?

Tags: apache-2.4, python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to setup python / apache / WSGI on windows.

I have the following installed, all 32-bit and vc9:

- Apache 2.4
- Python 2.7.9
- Mod_WSGI.so in the modules folder.

http://localhost/ Displays the Apache Haus web page successfully -- Apache is running and serving.

Here is my "Hello World" python script:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'This is my Website!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Here is my Apache config:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py"
<Directory "C:/wsgi_app">
AllowOverride None
Options MultiViews
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This version will display the file in plain-text, rather than interpreting it.

If I change options to none...

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py"
<Directory "C:/wsgi_app">
AllowOverride None
Options none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I get 404 Not Found on http://localhost/wsgi

The apache error log doesn't have much that seems too useful for troubleshooting.

```
[Wed Feb 10 16:17:49.293987 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4448:tid 336] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9+.
[Wed Feb 10 16:17:49.293987 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4448:tid 336] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
[Wed Feb 10 16:17:49.325187 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4448:tid 336] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 10 16:17:52.538793 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4448:tid 1040] [client ::1:54402] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py
```

"LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so" is uncommented, if that matters.

Any ideas on how to get this page to load / other apache config changes to try?

Do I need to change a python config somewhere?

Comment: Did you read the contents of the error log you published? E.g., "Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py"

Comment: @some1, what is the content of `C:/wsgi_app` directory? Can you post an exact listing of the files in this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you are getting:

> [wsgi:error] [pid 4448:tid 1040] [client ::1:54402] Target WSGI script
>   not found or unable to stat: C:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py

It is highly likely that you have no file with the name "wsgi_app.py" in the "C:/wsgi_app/" directory.

Now what does the `Options Multiviews` do?

Here is a quote from [Apache 2.4 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.

As you can see from the above explanation, when Multiviews option is enabled, and since a file named `wsgi_app.py` doesn't exist, the server will try to look for files named `wsgi_app.py.*`.

I suspect you have a file named `wsgi_app.py.txt` in the directory, and it's content get's displayed. You have probably created a text file in windows to create the wsgi_app.py file. In Windows when folder option "hide known file type extensions" is enabled, then it will hide the `.txt` extension of a file. As a result, a file named `wsgi_app.py.txt` will just be shown as `wsgi_app.py`.

When there is no Multiviews option anymore, the server is looking for a file exactly named "wsgi_app.py", and returning the error, being unable to find it.

Comment: Yep, sooo much hassle b/c windows hid the file extension and I completely forgot it does that.  Thank you.